# Fastest way to rewrite only one subpath

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a website developed in Classic ASP.NET and running on IIS 7.5. It works okay. But now I have the task to add affiliate program to my website. I want my reflink to looks like `www.mywebsite.com/r/userid`. Well, I googled around and found I can:

1. Use UrlRewrite third-party `HttpModule`s. As I understand, they are based on `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` web.config setting. Theoretically, I can:
2. Set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` and do `RewritePath` in `Application_BeginRequest` manually. But my `Application_BeginRequest` already contains a bit of code. It is too heavy to send all pages, images etc. to `Application_BeginRequest` because of one rarely called URL.

So, the question is how can I rewrite only subpath that starts with `www.mywebsite.com/r/`, and do not call  `Application_BeginRequest` for every image, css etc.? Best if no third-party things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finished up with HttpModule.

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="ReflinkModule" preCondition="" type="www.ReflinkModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

ReflinkModule.cs:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
}

public void BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        return;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request == null)
        return;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == null)
        return;
    string start = "/r/";
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.StartsWith(start))
        return;
    string key = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Substring(start.Length);
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Xxxxx.aspx?r=" + key);
}
```